# how to print same characters in a row in haskell

Tags: haskell

when I enter for example gggiiss as input, the output should be ggg.

```
round :: String -> String
round []=[]
round [x]=[x]
round (x:xs) = if xs == x then [x] ++ xs + round(xs)
else [x]
```

Code above is what I've written but I've got a lot of errors which I don't understand. Anyone knows how to correct it? Given that the first line of the code is compulsory

Comment: please provide more information and error messages

Comment: `xs` is always gonna be a list, so it will never equal `x`. Also if it's not an assignment, there are library functions for this, have a look at `takeWhile` and `group`

Comment: I have fixed the markdown syntax in your post; however, I wasn't sure exactly how to fix one part of it. Please review my edits and make sure the location of `else` in the post matches the way you've included `else` in the file you're trying to load.

Answer (score 3):

```
round :: String -> String
```

You say your function takes a string as input and produces a string as output.  This is good and consistent with your example of `round "gggiiss" == "ggg"`.

```
round [] = []
```

Your base case is an empty list input is an empty list output, sounds good.

```
round [x] = [x]
```

Another base case of a single element.  So I suppose that means the next case will require two or more elements right? ...

```
round (x:xs) = ...
```

Oh no, what happened here?  You require only one element (`xs` can be `[]`).  You probably wanted two element and the rest of the list `round (x1:x2:xs) ...`.

```
if xs == x
```

Well that makes no sense.  You can't compare the list, xs (such as `"ggiiss"`), with a single value, x (such as `'g'`).   If you used `x1` and `x2` as I showed above then `x1 == x2` would make sense as those are both characters.

```
then [x] ++ xs + round(xs)
```

What does it mean to add two strings togther, `xs + round xs`?  A more sensible strategy is probably concatenation `then [x1] ++ round (x2:xs)`.  I preserved the `x2` so in the recursive case you'd compare for the correct character.

```
else [x]
```

It is probably a copy/paste issue, but that `else` should be indented as far as the `then` case.  The final code is:

```
rnd :: String -> String
rnd []=[]
rnd [x]=[x]
rnd (x1:x2:xs) = if x1 == x2 then [x1] ++ rnd(x2:xs) else [x1]
```

P.S. You are getting downvotes for a number of reasons.  I'm guessing, but chief among them is that you didn't post the full "here is the code", "this is the intent", "here is how I'm invoking the code", and "here is the error".  SO is pretty explicit about asking users to post errors and expectations with the code and users have grown restless when that doesn't happen.